# Replacing a string in an array of strings in C

Tags: arrays, c, string

I'm having trouble replacing a string in an array of strings in C

Basically, I have:

`char * words[3];`

Now let's say the strings in there are "cat", "dog", "bird".

Now, I have a char word[] which contains "mouse", and I want to replace "dog" with "mouse' in the array.

I've tried using `strcpy(words[2], word);` but this doesn't work as expected and I'm assuming it's because the length of mouse is larger than that of dog. So, I'm wondering how would you go about accomplishing this task in this situation.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: how do you initialize words array?

Comment: Trouble is, `char * words[3];` doesn't declare an array of strings but an array of pointers. An array of 3 strings would be something like `char words[3][100];`, where each string has a maximum length of 99 chars (plus the required `nul` terminator). Which do you want: string array or pointer array?

Comment: I think you meant `strcpy(words[1], word);`? You can assign `words[1] = word;` (`words[1]` is just a pointer), but make sure you do not use `words[1]` beyond the lifetime of `word`.

Comment: You should update this question with code showing how you assign initial values to `words`, as this will reveal information about the situation. It appears you are just learning about handling strings in C, and there are multiple issues to be discussed about differences between copying strings versus copying pointers to them, ensuring there is enough space for a string, and more. Also, never describe a problem merely as “this doesn't work as expected”. Always describe what actually happened and what you expected to happen instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char* words[3] = {"cat", "dog", "bird"};
    
    printf("The Initial List\n");
    for(int i=0; i<3; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d : %s\n", i, words[i]);
    }
    
    // Replace the middle entry
    char* replacement = "mouse";
    words[1] = replacement;
    
    printf("The Final List\n");
    for(int i=0; i<3; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d : %s\n", i, words[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

### Output:

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0.01s 5464KB
The Initial List
0 : cat
1 : dog
2 : bird
The Final List
0 : cat
1 : mouse
2 : bird
```

Comment: Code without explanation is not a good answer. For this question, issues of lifetime and string literals versus allocated space should be discussed.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
char * words[3];
words[0] = "cat";
words[1] = "dog";
words[2] = "bird";
```

...is roughly equivalent to:

```
// Internal memory you can't see:
char _string1[] = {'c','a','t','\0'} // Address 0x001234
char _string2[] = {'d','o','g','\0'} // Address 0x001238
char _string3[] = {'b','i','r','d','\0'} // Address 0x001242

// Your program memory:
char * words[3];
words[0] = (char *)0x001234;
words[1] = (char *)0x001238;
words[2] = (char *)0x001242;
```

The important thing is `char * s` is not the same as `char s[]`, so trying to copy "mouse" over 0x001238 doesn't do what you want.

Given `char word[] = "mouse";`, `word` does have an address so you can assign that as in `words[1] = word;` and that will work. Of course if you change `word[0] = 'h';` to make it "house" then `words[1]` will also be "house".

If that's not a problem for you, then it's fine, otherwise you'll need `words` to be an array of characters rather than an array of pointers, and make sure there are enough characters to hold all the words you want. Since most words will be shorter than that, a lot of characters will be unused, but that's not normally a big problem.

Otherwise you will have to use `malloc()`, `free()`, `strdup()`, and so on to manage the memory and that gets complicated, so best avoid that unless you really need to.

Answer (score 0):

The following code shows one way to do it.  Note that we provide enough space (10 chars) for the future "mouse" strcpy().  This is an important point because the original declaration:

```
char * words[3];
```

... only sets aside space for 3 pointers of type char.  You cannot safely strcpy() to those pointers even if they are initialized with strings in the declaration.

Tested, runnable code is [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Ef4Wex3dj)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* A multi-dimensional array with enough space for 3 strings 
of 9 characters each -- plus the terminating NUL ('\0') for 
each string. (3x10) We can safely strcpy() "mouse" to an 
array like this.*/
char  words[3][10] = {"cat", "dog", "bird"};
char  word[] = "mouse";

int main()
{
int iii;

    for(iii = 0; iii < 3; iii++)
        printf("%s\n", words[iii]);

    strcpy(words[2], word);
    printf("\n");

    for(iii = 0; iii < 3; iii++)
        printf("%s\n", words[iii]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
cat
dog
bird

cat
dog
mouse
```

Comment: Runnable code [here](https://godbolt.org/z/9ThcGTbcc)

Comment: Code without explanation is not a good answer, and this code changes the questions definition of `words` without discussing the implications.

Comment: Hi @Eric Postpischil -- did you miss my comment?  I felt it best to include my explanation as a comment this time, so it could be placed close to the array definition... thx

Comment: A brief comment is insufficient discussion of the implications of the change, which include issues of lifetime, differences between copying the contents of a string versus copying a pointer to the string, and more. This is not a good answer. To be fair, that is partly because the question is not a good question; it leaves too many things open. But that leaves it incumbent upon a good answer to address multiple issues that a student will be learning at this stage.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil -- thank you very much for taking time to mentor me on this.  Noted.  Thx again.

Comment: @user3386109  -- thank you for your edit to bring my comment into better compliance as an explanation.  I'll keep in mind for future posts.  Thx again.

Answer (score 0):

You are right : it is not possible to enhance the size of the string, because each pointer in the array points to a constant string. Here is how you can visualize the memory layout :
[image: memory layout]

You may declare your array in a way that gives enough space for each string, i.e.

```
char words[3][256] = {"cat", "dog", "bird"};
```

In fact, as these are constants, the array should be declared const and you should avoid to modify these strings in a real-world program.

Comment: If the array were declared as you show, `char words[3][256]`, then also declaring it `const` as you suggest would make it impossible to do what the question requests, replacing one of the strings.

Comment: Precisely : "you should avoid to modify these strings in a real-world program."

Comment: Yes, you tell the OP to avoid modifying the strings, but that does not alter the fact that using `const` would not provide a solution to their request. They asked for help replacing a string, and using `const` makes that impossible. The array should **not** be declared `const` because its contents are not intended to be constant. (Also, initializing them with string literals does not make them constants.)